# Difference between onActivityResult and onComplete of Session.StatusCallback Facebook Android sdk3.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-authorization

I'm using Facebook Android sdk3.0.
I want to do something after user successfully log in through Facebook. 
Should I implement it inside `onActivityResult` or the `onComplete` function of `Session.StatusCallback`?

Actually is there any difference between the two? Can I assume Session.StatusCallback onComplete is always called after `onActivityResult` ?

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // Do Something Here?
}


private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {

    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

        if (session.isOpened()) {
             // Or Do Something Here?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is, you should do both.

onActivityResult is needed because you need to pass on the information to the Facebook SDK in order for the SDK to verify that the user has accepted the terms and permissions. Once the SDK verifies everything, it will then call the SessionStatusCallback.call with the new state, or any errors that occurred.

When you're opening a new session, it will first transition to the OPENING state (which will call your callback), then it will do the SSO, when SSO completes, your onActivityResult will be called (at which time you should call session.onActivityResult or uiLifecycleHelper.onActivityResult), then the session will transition to the OPENED state, which will call your callback again.